# Why are the key words abstract and void in a php Interface?

Tags: php, oop, abstract

Going over The SplSubject interface on the php manual site and noticed.

```
SplSubject {

  /* Methods */
  abstract public void attach ( SplObserver $observer )
  abstract public void detach ( SplObserver $observer )
  abstract public void notify ( void )
}
```

I can't figure out what the key word "abstract" does in the code or why it is there. Also never seen/used a function return type in php (Such as void)?

Thank you

Comment: `SplSubject {` What is this? A class, interface, abstract class?

Comment: @Rizier123 http://php.net/manual/en/class.splsubject.php

Comment: The interface declaration shown there is pseudo code. Especially the return type you'll see often in such "declarations" on the PHP manual. The `abstract` keyword makes no sense for me too. I'm curious what others will say....

Comment: @hek2mgl Ah lol okay; I think `SplSubject` is similar to a interface, since you implement it and not extend from it. The abstract keyword is there to say to every class which implements this that they have to define the behavior of this function. The void i think is only from documenting it an is just a type hint

Comment: Probably you are right.. Normally all interface methods need to get implemented - without the need of the abstract keyword. But hey, it is pseudo code and that's why they added that to make it more "clear"...

Comment: @hek2mgl Yep it's really weird the entire documentation, but if you take a look at the comments under it: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splsubject.php#107688 You see it how someone is implementing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface declaration you've seen there is *pseudo code*. Meaning it is not meant to be executable PHP code.

They have added the type info for the obvious reason of showing the expected return type of the method.

Don't ask me why they have chosen to explicitly add the `abstract` keyword. Normally every method declared in an interface is "abstract". Probably they wanted to emphasize that.

Comment: Also just to add to this answer see this link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php Under Example 4: `An interface, together with type-hinting, provides a good way to make sure that a particular object contains particular methods` So this explains the type hinting in the documentation, but still the explicit abstract is weird

Comment: The site should probably place the "type hinting" explanation in a less obscure place.