# what is difference between passing void as a parameter and not passing it to function?

Tags: php, void

I got confused while reading code from php mannual --

what is difference in below two syntaxes --

```
final public string Exception::getMessage ()
```

vs

```
final public string Exception::getMessage ( void )
```

As Manuel says this function has no parameter, then what is purpose of passing that void there. Although void its self represent that it will be having noting. So my questions are --

1- Which one is most standard way in both syntaxes and why ?

http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

Comment: The 2nd one is just a documentation example that the function takes no arguments, you don't have to actually type the word `void`. Just use the syntax from your 1st example.

Comment: Second one isn't even valid php code.

Comment: @Dan second one should be valid as i have picked it from mannual

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are the key words abstract and void in a php Interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28569326)

Comment: If you were to use the code with the `void` word in the function argument, I think PHP would complain about a constant not being defined.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this code ? @Abhishek

Comment: Thanks to all of you for giving me better insights

Comment: Think of it as a void cheque ;-) [*not valid or legally binding.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`void` is not an actual language construct. It's just used for decorative purposes in the manual.

See <s>`http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php`</s>(dead link)

> **void**
>
> void as a return type means that the return value is useless. void in a parameter list means that the function doesn't accept any parameters.
>
> <sub>PHP Manual, © 1997-2015 the PHP Documentation Group, CC-BY-SA 3.0</sub>

Comment: It's a hold-over from C. In C, `int main()` declares a function with a variable number of parameters, while `int main(void)` declares a function with no parameters. PHP, though, does not use `void` in parameter lists.

Answer (score 6):

Well, [let's try](https://3v4l.org/FB6Wb):

```
class Foo{
    function bar(void){
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE or ... in /in/FB6Wb on line 4

So the difference is that the former actually runs :)

Now seriously, that's nothing but a syntax used in documentation to explain method signatures, you aren't expected to *type* it as-is. The syntax uses [pseudo-types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php) to express variables and you can check the [How to read a function definition (prototype)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php) annex to get a grasp of other syntax bits (like using square brackets for optional arguments).